Is it legal or illegal to print your fanfiction story into a physical book even if it's just for yourself only and not for profit?
I keep hearing all sorts of answers online about printing your fanfiction story into a physical book. Either it's okay or not okay to do as it is illegal and can break copyright. I can accept that it is illegal if that's the case. I'm just hoping to find another way that isn't besides DIY.
Printing it at a professional place like a book printing service, print on demand or self-publishing seems like the only way since I want to have a professional print my fanfiction story into a physical book since I have no knowledge or experience in DIY. Unless there is another kind of way to print your fanfiction story into a physical book. But at the same time, I don't want to do anything illegal.
I just want to find a possible way to have my fanfiction story become one physical book for myself without having to share it with anyone and not make money out of it. And after hearing all those answers online, I just don't know what to believe. I'm truly at a loss and all this has stressed me out. If anyone can help me figure all this out, I would appreciate it.

You can print whatever you want for your own private use, but you cannot distribute it in any way, even if you give it away for free and only to friends.

So I can print professionally at a book printing service, print on demand or self-publishing this fanfiction story for myself only? Perhaps it would be easier to contact these types of places to ensure that fanfiction is okay for them to print or not?

@Beth (1) Yes. (2) You need to ask permission of the copyright holder. (I don't know who that might be in your case.)

Copyright holder as in the original author and publisher of the original book? Or just ask the places where I want to ask for their services of printing my fanfiction?

@Beth Again, if you print this for yourself and don't want to distribute it, you don't need to ask anyone. If you want to publish it (that is, give or sell copies to someone), you need permission from the copyright holder. In the case of fanfiction, that may be the copyright holder of the fanfiction (for their work) and the copyright holder of the original work. Read here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legal_issues_with_fan_fiction. It is unlikely, though, that you will get that permission.

In this case, all I want to do is find a way to print my fanfiction story into a physical book for myself only, not for profit and without breaking any copyright laws and doing it legally.

@Beth And what remains unclear about "You can print whatever you want for your own private use"?

Sorry. Like I mentioned above in the original post. After hearing all those answers online, I just don't know what to believe. I'm just really scared that if I do this, I will get into trouble if I do something illegal and break copyright law. Also, I just want to double-check since the answer wasn't clear. If I just print my fanfiction story into a physical book for myself only, I won't need permission from anyone including the original author and publisher? And it's a good idea to talk to the book printing places to ensure that it's okay to print the book at their places?

@Beth Yes, you do not need permission if you print it only for your self and don't distribute it. No, you don't need to ask the printer. They don't care, because they have nothing to fear.

I don't know about that. About not asking the book printing service, print on demand or self-publishing about printing my fanfiction that is. Still, better safe than sorry and just ask.
